# Standardized coefficients for a fixed effects model in R

Tags: r, regression, time-series, panel-data, fixed-effects-model

I need to assess the relative impact of my coefficients. I work with R and for my OLS model I am using the `lm.beta` package. However, it does not work with fixed effects models for panel data. Could you recommend an alternative?

Comment: I answered a similar question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/463370/do-we-need-to-demean-and-standardize-all-variables-in-a-model).

Comment: Thank you Rob, it works perfectly. Thomas, yours is a valid point too; I agree with your logic, but what I want is to have a measure of the relative importance of variables, and standardization is the only way to do this that I am aware of. Is there a better way that is mode consistent with the FE approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest standardising the variables before running your regression models! Those standardised variables will work with any sort of regression model and give you coefficients on the same scale!

Some guidance on standardising variables here: https://data-se.netlify.app/2021/02/26/how-to-standardize-variables-in-r/

Plenty of other resources too!